# How to make api requests to sabre / travel api (node js app)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sabre

I am using the travel api from sabre and cannot make any http requests to any endpoint but 1. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Im also not sure if I need a token since its just a test developer account and as I understand,I wouldn't need to require token?!  if anyone has some experience with the saber api or api requests (maybe my code is wrong for other reasons) any help would be super much appreciated!! Thanks!!
Ps. I am using nodejs.

Api code that works:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var SabreDevStudio = require('sabre-dev-studio');
var sabre_dev_studio = new SabreDevStudio({
  client_id:     'V1:xxx',
  client_secret: 'xxx',
  uri:           'https://api.test.sabre.com'
});
var options = {};

router.get('/allcities', function (req, res) {
    sabre_dev_studio.get('/v1/lists/supported/shop/themes', options,  function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(200).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Api call (below) to get the lowest fares of picked destination doesn't work. In sabre's documentation I find this:

GET https://api.havail.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights/cheapest/fares/DFW HTTP/1.1 
   documentation: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/flights_to/

```
router.get('/lowestFare', function(req,res){
    sabre_dev_studio.get('/v1/shop/flights/cheapest/fares/DFW HTTP/1.1', options, function(err, data){
        if (err){
            res.status(200).send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    })
})
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to send requests to SOAP or HTTP sabre API's you need to have spoken to a Sabre account manager and/or signed a contract with Sabre. They will inform you which environments you have access and to which Sabre APIs you have access.

I presume you are only interested in the REST API's, namely the HTTP REST API 'Bargain Finder Max (BFM)', which is sabre's best-in-class low fare search product, used to search for the lowest available priced itineraries based upon a specific date. The 'Bargain Finder Max (BFM)' requires activation, documentation advises you to contact your Sabre Account Representative for assistance.

Firstly click [here](https://developer.sabre.com/member/register) to obtain API key for test purposes. Register an account.

Obtain your personal 'key' and 'shared secret' after registration.

Click [here](https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs) for the test environment to get familiar with the REST API's.

The cheapest air search endpoint is part of the 'Air Search' HTTP REST API. This is an endpoint which supports HTTP GET requests to find the 20 lowest published fares available for a given destination (destination required; the destination parameter is a 3-letter IATA airport code or city code of the arrival airport e.g. LAX - Los Angeles). Also you submit a pointofsalecountry parameter which is just a 2-letter country code of the point of sale e.g. US.

Using the API explorer invoke a HTTP GET request to the following URI:

https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights/cheapest/fares/LAX?pointofsalecountry=US

In terms of your Express.js JavaScript code, you've setup a middleware callback function for GET requests to '/lowestFare' which in turn seems to send a HTTP GET request to the following URL: '/v1/shop/flights/cheapest/fares/DFW HTTP/1.1' this is not a valid URL and doesn't seem to have any query string or request data / options sent with it.

See this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-NodeJs) with a complete examples for consuming sabre REST API's with Node.js. The readme file here also states: 'Please register at https://developer.sabre.com contact Sabre in order to obtain your own credentials.'

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It actually works for me since about a minute. I didn't have to speak to anyone (i don't think that applies when Im just testing apis) and after I created a token on saber website (using my client-id and secret), my api requests actually work (not the one I posted though-but others like the cheap fares api). Im kind of confused though, since I am not using the token in my code/request-I only generated it for (for example the cheapest fare api) and thats all but after that it started working..